# Cannot display image inserted by WYSIWYG editor

Tags: magento-1, frontend, url, wysiwyg

I created a form on backend and inserted an image into the editor. The image displays properly in the editor. However, the image cannot be displayed on frontend and 404 error is shown on the console. How to solve it? Thank you in advance.

Image tag generated by Magento:

```
<img alt="" src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg"}}"="">
```

Error Message:

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/%7B%7Bmedia%20url= Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**Update (06-10-2015 12:33):**

It seems that the cause of the problem may be wysiwyg configuration.

In the php file where the wysiwyg editor is added, if I change the wysiwyg configuration to the following:

```
$fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
        ......
        'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig()
    ));
```

The admin panel even cannot find the image insert page and the image inserted before also disappears from the editor. Besides that, the content from WYSIWYG is output by PHP. Will it be the cause?

This is my current wysiwyg configuration:

```
$wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig();
$wysiwygConfig->addData(array(
        'add_variables'             => false,
        'plugins'                   => array(),
        'widget_window_url'         => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/widget/index'),
        'directives_url'            => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive'),
        'directives_url_quoted'     => preg_quote(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive')),
        'files_browser_window_url'  => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index'),
    ));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. The cause of the problem is *unprocessed shortcodes* in the `html` content, which is the `{{ media url="..." }}` statement. Before `echo` this statement, the *html content* should be process by the processor from *helper "cms"*. Below is the code:

```
$html_content = $content_from_db['content'];
$html_content = Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($html_content);
echo $html_content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it to:

```
<img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg"}}">
```

**Edit:**

You might also want to try it with different quotes:

```
<img alt="" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg'}}">
```

And make sure that the media/wysiwyg folder has the correct permissions

**Edit 2:**

Because you are using the CMS content in a custom template, you can also use direct links like this:

```
<img alt="" src="/media/wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg">
```

This will work if the media is hosted on the same domain, and the Magento install is not in a subfolder. If it's located in a subfolder use the following:

```
<img alt="" src="/subfolder/media/wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg">
```

**Edit 3:**

If you want to display a static block in a custom phtml template, you can do the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Where block_identifier is the block identifier.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this statement is generated by Magento. On backend WYSIWYG editor, the url is identical to yours, but on frontend, the url is different.

Comment: The image tag you show in your example is different from the one I posted though?

Comment: Yes. The url I posted is retrieved from "Inspect Element" function of Chrome. It is different from yours. Moreover, The wired thing is that the <img> tag is also identical to yours from "View Page Source" function of Chrome.

Comment: The image tag you posted (not the error message), is formatted incorrectly. You should use the image tag from my answer and it should work fine. If it doesn't work, please post the error message here and I will have a look. If the error message is exactly the same as the previous one, the page must is maybe cached by a full page cache system.

Comment: I checked the image tag on WYSIWYG editor and the image tag on the editor is the same as the one given by you. The error message is still the one I posted.

Comment: Can you post the error message again or the url of the page so I can check for you? The error message corresponds with the image tag you posted, but it shouldn't appear with the fixed image tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am sorry that the website is locally hosted, so there is no public url. And the "404" error I posted really is the only error message I got.

Comment: In the error message the part http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/%7B%7Bmedia%20url= is still the same or different?

Comment: I added two other suggestions to my answer

Comment: The url part of the error was still the same. After I change the double quote to single quote, the error message changed to http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/%7B%7Bmedia%20url='wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg'%7D%7D Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What happens if you paste the following in the page? {{media url='wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg'}}

Comment: So without the image tag

Comment: It displays as plaintext.

Comment: What does it display, can you paste the text>

Comment: {{media url='wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg'}}

Comment: You should paste it in the non-visual (plain text) editor. So toggle the editor using the show/hide editor button, and then paste it. The same goes for the image tag shown in my example.

Comment: Yes, I pasted the statement to the plaintext editor, which is the one without  styling function, but it was displayed directly.

Comment: That's strange indeed. Are the other variables working when you insert them? And the default Magento demo cms pages, are these displaying images? Maybe it's some kind of charset issue making the system not recognize the accolades {{

Comment: Is your database set to use UTF-8?

Comment: Also, did you put the {{media url='wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg'}} in an empty page, or does the page contain other stuff? Best try in an empty page first to debug.

Comment: The database is using UTF-8. {{media url='wysiwyg/screen_shot_2015-09-23_at_2.43.13_am.jpg'}} will show the corresponding URL properly if this statement is pasted on a new blank page.

Comment: In that case there must be a misplaced quote somewhere in the html. Try pasting it in a html editor, or use our syntax highlighter extension to check for errors https://plugin.company/magento-extensions/syntax-highlighter.html

Comment: Here is the git url by the way, no need to order it from our site, you can just download from github https://github.com/PluginCompany/magento-syntax-highlighter

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just want to update that the image insert function works properly on other pages.

Comment: I just update the problem. If I change the wysiwyg editor configuration, the image even cannot be displayed in the backend.

Comment: If the image insert function works fine on other pages, there is an issue with the html of the current cms page. You should check the html step by step and test.

Comment: It is a custom module, so I get the content from database using php in the phtml file and echo it using php. May it be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Yes, that must be the problem. In CMS pages and blocks the variables {{ }} are replaced. This won't work if you take the data directly from the database. Please see my updated answer for a solution.

Comment: Thank you @MilanSimek. It works. However, is there any way to display the image without modifying the img tag?

Comment: My pleasure. Yes, you can edit your phtml file and echo a static block there. Then the variables in the block should work fine. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Do you mean creating a new block in my custom module to display the content and get the block in the phtml?

Comment: You can create a block, and then indeed echo the block in your custom module .phtml. So that way you can still use the wysiwyg editor variables

Comment: What do I need to do it that block? What currently in my mind is creating a block.php file in my custom module and define _toHtml() function in that file. In the _toHtml() function, I get the content and return it. Am i correct? I am really thank you for your patience.

Comment: You can do that, or you can just paste the last code I put in the answer in the phtml file. Then create a new cms block with the same identifier.

Comment: I don't know what to do after pasting your code. For example, how to I get the cms block created by your code in order to input the WYSIWYG content to the block? Or when do I need to echo the WYSIWYG content.

Comment: I created a new block php file and connect to that phtml file. I retrieve the WYSIWYG content from database in the block php file and pass the content to phtml. However, it still does not work.

Comment: How do you retrieve it from the database? If you add the cms block code that I posted in your phtml file, and set the `block_identifier` to `my_custom_block`, you can now create a cms block in the back-end with the identifier `my_custom_block`. The content will then be displayed.

Comment: I discovered the cause of problem. It is because the shortcodes in that html content has not been processed. I posted the answer. Really thank you for your help, @MilanSimek